# Simple exponent algebra question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Suppose we have

$$10^{-2^{n+1}} \cdot 10^{a2^{n}}$$

How does this simplify down to

$$10^{(a-2)2^n}$$

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Try to expand the result

Comment: Start by using the property $$10^x *10^y = 10^{x+y}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have exponentials with the same base [10] and you are multiplying them so we sum up the exponents$$-2^{n+1}+a2^n$$
You can write $-2^{n+1}$ as $-2^n \cdot 2$ and also $2^n \cdot -2$ sampling this we have $$2^n(-2)+2^na$$ here we just take out the common factor $2^n$ and we have $$2^n(-2+a) $$ or   $2^n(a-2)$ which is what we were looking for then we plug the base and we have $$10^{2^n(a-2)}$$